# Negative lookahead not matching as expected

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I´m trying to replace some word in a string using `preg_replace()`. I need to check if the word is not followed by any of this set `[a-zA-Z0-9_$.]`. In order to achieve this, I'm using **negative lookahead**, so, for example, if the target word is `"foo"` and I have a string like:

```
"hello_foo this foo is an example.foo"
```

... and I want to replace `foo` with `bar` using this regex

```php
$old = "hello_foo this foo is an example.foo";

$new = preg_replace("/(?![a-zA-Z0-9_$.])foo/", "bar" $old);
```

...this should return

```
"hello_foo this bar is an example.foo"
```

which is not working as expected. **But**, if I remove the `a-z` set from the regex, it does work,  but now it would replace words like this `"aaafoo"` to `"aaabar"`.

Am I missing something here? I'm new to regex.

Comment: don't need a negative lookahead, just capture also the negative chars and refer it in replace

Comment: `preg_replace("/([^a-zA-Z0-9_$.])foo/", "$1bar" , $old); `

Comment: I think you mean a negative lookbehind `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9_$.])foo` https://regex101.com/r/SdiGte/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, I though `lookahead` and `lookbehind` were the same, it seems to work now.